# Knockout : component within component

Tags: knockout.js

In my pet-(also test-)project, I succeeded in using knockout components with custom elements, so my index.html page looks something like this :

```
[snip]

<backup></backup>
<management></management>
<process></process>

[snip]
```

All three are custom elements, and have their own viewmodel and markup in seperate files. The ko.components.registration is done in the main.js of require.

However, the management.html is also a big chunk of markup, that could be divided further in separate custom elements like so :

```
<categories></categories>
<products></products>
<parts></parts>
```

But alas, so far I just fail to get these components working within the management component. Note that the viewmodels of these 3 parts are injected by require in the management viewmodel. (Which works fine if I don't use components, but ordinary divs with data-bind="with:viewmodel").

So my question is : is this possible with knockout ? And if so, what am I doing wrong ? (in other words, do you have some tips why it's not working ?)

UPDATE
After some tweaking all the components get registered. But still, the inner component does not get rendered.... To be continued...

UPDATE - EUREKA !
I've got it working. Turns out that in the parent component markup, I can't use a custom element, it has to be a div with databind='component : "categories"'. But now it's working fine, and everything is neatly separated ! Hooray !

Comment: You should be able to put those elements right in the template for management. The only caveat is that you will need to fetch the viewmodel for the subelements first. Have you looked at the Knockout documentation for template / viewmodel loading?

Comment: Thanks Jimmy for your answer. Yes, I have looked at the ko doc, but or they give a simple example, or they give explanations that I don't understand. But I will look at it again soon (outside of the working hours ! :-) )

Comment: If you want to know more about my pet-project : http://a-html5-app-from-scratch.blogspot.be/

Comment: @ErwinB About your update, you can use custom elements in both the parent and child components. I never tested it using require but as for the common method described in the docs using strings and functions to create them, it works perfectly